# Is it possible to connect USB wifi adapter directly into router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, network-adapter, wireless-adapter

Is it possible to use a USB wifi adapter (or similar device) to plug directly into the USB socket of a router so you can use the wifi of the adapter rather than the wifi of the router but still use the router normally?

The router in question is called a Netduma so it's not one of the big branded routers. I don't have a make/model wifi adapter in mind as it was just a general question of if it was possible.

Comment: This depends on the router and the USB adapter. There is no one answer which fits all situations.

Comment: It really boils down to a couple of questions: Does your router even have a USB port (not all do), and is the router running an OS for which you can obtain drivers for your particular USB adapter?

Comment: The Netduma has a USB 2.0 port but there is no mention anywhere of what it is for. YOu shouldask them on the support furum.

Comment: ok thanks. I will mention it on there and see if anyone knows.